# Using multiple where(or AND) which have nested or condition?

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongoose, sails.js, waterline

How can one query in mongodb using Waterline ORM in Sailjs, with multiple AND condition each of them having nested OR conditions.

An Example MySQL query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE (score IS NULL OR activity IS NULL) AND (invited IS NULL OR invited_by IS NULL)
```

Using multiple .where() doesn't seems to be working, also using all condition in OR prop destroy the logic.

Any solutions around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it is within the scope of the your expected solution but why don't .query() method .

```
Users.query('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE (score IS NULL OR activity IS NULL) AND (invited IS NULL OR invited_by IS NULL)', [ ] ,function(err, result) {
  if (err) { // do something }
  else {// do something else with the result}


});
```

P.S. : I have not run  this query directly . There may be some syntax error on my part.

Please look into this page for more reference 
http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/query

EDIT :  Sorry , I misunderstood the question , However with mongoDB you have to use the native()  method .  It should be Something like

```
var queryCriteria = {
   "$and" : [{"$or" : [{ "score" : null },{"activity" : null}] },{"$or" : [{ 
 "invitedby" : null },{"invited" : null}] } ]
}
```

Then you can use the  native method like this

```
Users.native(function(error, collection) {
  if (error) return res.serverError(error);

  collection.find(queryCriteria ,{}).toArray(function (err, results) {
    if (err) return res.serverError(err);
    return res.ok(results);
  });
});
```

P.P.S : MongoDB  does not have a schema . So if you have not entered null explicitly while creating data , the field will not be created  i.e the data may not have a score field  at all , In that case you must replace null will {$exists : false} . Also I have used this native method before , In my 
 very limited experience it is pretty slow .. I remember getting a transactionPerSecond of only around 10  in one of my cases . Please see to it .

Link for .native()   http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/native

Comment: i am trying run the query in Mongodb, if you see the question i want to map the example mysql query into mongodb using waterline model (if its possible).

Comment: Yes, that's right actually, default waterline has very limited support.
Thanks Anyway.